# Как передается методу View() имя экшена

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

если просто из экшена возвращать View() не передавая ему ничего, то возвращается вьюха по названию экшена, как передается это самое название?

Answer (score 2):

Это название никак не передается. В этом случае срабатывает стандартный алгоритм поиска файлов представления. Razor view engine будет искать файлы в таком порядке:

```
~/Views/[ControllerName]/[ActionName].cshtml
~/Views/[ControllerName]/[ActionName].vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/[ActionName].cshtml
~/Views/Shared/[ActionName].vbhtml
```

---

**UPD.** Интересующий вас код находится в классе [`ViewResultBase`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewResultBase.cs), наследниками которого являются `ViewResult` и `PartialViewResult`. Перед выполнением поиска файла представления выполняется такая проверка:

```
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // ...

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewName))
        {
            ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        // ...
```